# Automatically derive configured codecs for all types

Tags: json, scala, circe

I currently use configured codecs to decode json into case classes. It looks as

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.AutoDerivation
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.extras.decoding.ConfiguredDecoder
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._
import shapeless.Lazy

final case class A(...)
final case class B(...)
final case class C(...)

object Cdcs extends AutoDerivation {
  implicit def configuration: Configuration = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames

  implicit def aDecoder: Decoder[A] = deriveConfiguredDecoder[A]
  implicit def bDecoder: Decoder[B] = deriveConfiguredDecoder[B]
  implicit def cDecoder: Encoder[C] = deriveConfiguredEncoder[C]
}
```

The problem is it is easily to forget to add a codec (I just did) when a new entity was added. So I'm curious how to automate configured decoder derivation. I tried

```
import io.circe.{Decoder, Encoder}
import io.circe.generic.AutoDerivation
import io.circe.generic.extras.Configuration
import io.circe.generic.extras.decoding.ConfiguredDecoder
import io.circe.generic.extras.semiauto._
import shapeless.Lazy

object Cdcs extends AutoDerivation {
  implicit def configuration: Configuration = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames
  implicit def configuredDecoder[Entity: Decoder](implicit
      decode: Lazy[ConfiguredDecoder[Entity]]
  ): Decoder[Entity] =
    deriveConfiguredDecoder[Entity]

}
```

But in this case the non-configured decoder is generated and applied. Is there a way to automate such `Decoder` generation? Maybe some macro would be helpful here?

Comment: Currently, you are using semiauto, instead, you can switch to auto derivation which circe by default provides. 
https://circe.github.io/circe/codecs/auto-derivation.html

Comment: I would simply use unit tests checking serialization format for all exposed models - if test fails to compile I forgot about a codec. Auto has the disadvantage that the same codec will be derived several times, on each call site, and that if you use some customization and fail to import it in some scope - you will have mismatching codecs.